# Priorities of individual threads Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've created three separate threads to do the same task, in the for loop display the console inscription.
I gave each thread a different priority through constructions(MIN, MED, MAX)

```
thread1.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY)
```

additionally I added stopping all threads through

```
final CyclicBarrier gate = new CyclicBarrier(4);
```

and, to run all threads in the same time.

```
 gate.await();
} catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
```

And at the and I started all threads

```
thread2.run();
thread1.run();
thread3.run();

 try {
gate.await();
} catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("DONE");
```

setting priorities does not give the intended effects, because the threads are executed in the order in which they were "launched" above
I am asking for help because I have no idea why the priority setting does not work.
Application running on android 4.4

Comment: What are the priorities to thread 2 and 3

Comment: thread1: MIN_PRIORITY
thread2: NORM_PRIORITY
thread3: MAX_PRIORITY

Comment: And on what order are they running as? Expected is: 1-2-3

Comment: in the same as above.
First t2 -> t1 -> t3
expected is 3->2->1